# Why does an Integer concatenated with a number result in a string?

Tags: java, casting

I was going through an AP Comp Sci practice test and found the following problem:

what is the output of:

```
System.out.println("1" + new Integer(2) + 3);
```

The answer was

```
123,
```

I am confused as the `new Integer(2)` has not been casted into a String and therefore why does the java compiler believe that the `new Integer(2) + 3` statement is a String concatenation if both parts are integers?

Comment: questions came from here: https://www.tracy.k12.ca.us/sites/clunetta/Java/practice/practice.htm

Comment: Because an object is evaluated for printing with `toString`.

Comment: Tip: change the title to something more specific to the problem at hand (so others with the same problem can reach the solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the answer as simple as order of operations meaning that the statement is evaluated left to right so it could read. 
System.out.println("1" + new Integer(2).toString() + 3.toString());

Comment: *This* expression is evaluated left to right because no operator precedence applies. However for clarity it is *operands* of a specific *operator* that are evaluated left to right, not entire expressions.

Answer (score 9):

Addition is left associative. a + b + c == (a + b) + c

Comment: So it first evaluates "1" + new Integer(2) which it believes to mean string concatenation (making) "12" and then "12" + 3 which it again assumes as concatenation to make "123"?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain why string concatenation is preferred. The left associative part is understandable. Meaning, why the integer becomes a string in both cases.

Comment: it makes sense since the first evaluation would be meaningless if it were not concatenation... thats why its preferred (correct me if my logic is wrong) and since this goes from left to right we end up with a bunch of concatenations

Comment: In Java, everything is an Object, and Object defines `toString()` function defined. When a string is needed, Java implicitly calls `toString()`. There's no "preference"; Java can't implicitly convert a String to an int, but it can go the other way because an int is an Object (kind of...).

Answer (score 0):

First, as the guy points out, addition is left-associative.

Second, the overload resolution of "1" + 2 is controlled by the left operand, which is a String.  That forces concatenation, and the result is "12".

Now, "12" + 3 goes through the exact same overload resolution, and you get "123".

Answer (score 0):

The original question was:

```
System.out.println("1" + new Integer(2) + 3);
```

and why does that give us "123"; I assume the questioner meant rather than 6 or "15"?

Let's simplify this and remove the new Integer bit to its equivalent:

```
System.out.println("1" + 2 + 3);
```

The Java Language Specification 12 gives the answer (4.2.2):

> The string concatenation operator + (§15.18.1), which, when given a String
>   operand and an integral operand, will convert the integral operand to a String
>   (the decimal form of a byte, short, int, or long operand, or the character
>   of a char operand), and then produce a newly created String that is the
>   concatenation of the two strings. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

The 15.18.1 section is even more clear:

> The additive operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative
>   (they group left-to-right).
>   If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the operation is string
>   concatenation.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

So, since the operator + is used in both cases, it evaluates left-to-right, whether it is concatenation or addition, as stated in 15.18.1 and as other answerers have stated. The first operand "1" is a string and the second an integer 2, so according to the above rule, the integer 2 is converted to a string "2" and the plus is interpreted as concatenation, giving us a string "12". Then it has a string "12" and an integer 3, so the integer 3 is converted according to the above rule and the + is again interpreted as concatenation and we get a string "123".

If they had put parentheses around the 2 + 3:

```
System.out.println("1" + (2 + 3));
```

That, obviously, would force the 2 + 3 to be evaluated first. They are both integers, so you get an integer 5. Then we would have "1" + 5, which is a string plus an integer, so the integer is converted to a string "5" and they are concatenated, yielding "15".

If they had changed the order like this:

```
System.out.println(2 + 3 + "1");
```

Then, the 2 + 3 would be done first in accordance with the left-to-right rule, and since they are both integers, + would mean addition and that would yield an integer 5. Then we would have operators integer 5 and a string "1". According to the above rule, the integer 5 is converted to a string 5 and the + is interpreted as concatenation and we get a string "51".

So this all boils down to order of operations, the fact that all of these operations are really binary (you only take two at a time), and, when using a plus sign, if one operand is a string, the other is changed to a string if it is not already one, the plus sign is interpreted as concatenation, and the result is a string.